# How to merge the results from ploop?

Tags: for-loop, parallel-processing, dolphindb

I defined a function that returns a table. Now I specified this function as the parameter of ploop, and it returns multiple tables.

So how can I merge these tables together? Could I use a for-loop or others?

Answer (score 0):

If the results are tables, you can use `unionAll` to merge them.

```
ploop(...).unionAll(false)
```

If the results are vectors, you can use `append!`

```
ploop(...).append!()
```